# Calculate 100 factorial with all the digits

Tags: perl, factorial, bigint

I came across a problem of calculating *100 factorial*.

Here is what I tried first in *Perl* to calculate **100!** :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $n=<>;
chomp($n);
print fac($n);

sub fac
{
    my ($m) = @_;

    return 1 if($m <=1 );
    return $m*fac($m-1);
}
```

But this is giving me `9.33262154439441e+157`.

I need the answer with all of the digits.

What do I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doubles (which most Perls use) only have ~16 digits of precision. You need to use another system to get the 158 digits of precision you need.

```
use bigint;
```

This will cause Perl to automatically treat all numbers in your script as `Math::BigInt` objects.

If you need finer control (to treat some numbers as `BigInt` and some numbers as floating point) then see Krishnachandra Sharma's solution and explicitly use the `Math::BigInt` constructor.

`Math::BigInt` has a builtin factorial function, by the way:

```
$ perl -MMath::BigInt -e 'print Math::BigInt->bfac(100)'
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 6):

Doubles (which most Perls use) only have ~16 digits of precision. You need to another system to get the 158 digits of precision you need. Try using [`Math::BigInt`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html).

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;


my $n=100;
Math::BigInt->new($n);
print fac($n);

sub fac
{
    my ($m) = @_;

    return 1 if($m <=1 );
    return Math::BigInt->new($m*fac($m-1));
}
```

Produces `9332621544394415268169923e266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `bigint` works by overloading handling of integer and floating point literals, converting them to Math::BigInt objects. So with the help of simple `for` loop we can achieve the factorial of very big integers.

```
use bigint;

my $fact = 1;

for my $n (1..100) {    
    $fact *= $n;
}

print "Factorial: \n", $fact , "\n";
```

This produces the below output:

```
Factorial: 933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214685929638952175
99993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000
000000000
```

whereas the normal program like this would tremble with no meaningful output

```
use integer;

my $fact = 1;

for my $n (1..100) {    
    $fact *= $n;
}

print "Factorial: \n", $fact , "\n";
```

Output:

```
Factorial:
0
```